# Websphere Application server not calling classes from jaxws jar

Tags: web-services, web-applications, jax-ws, apache-axis, websphere-7

I am using jaxws-ri to create the stub from webservices.I have deployed the application on tomcat and it is working fine.Now I want to move to websphere 7.0. when I deploy the same war the login page is seen but when the call to the webservice is made the application throws an error.

```
 LoginAction : execute : catch : WebServiceExceptionjavax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.SoapSecurityException: WSEC5509E: A security token whose type is [http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken] is required.
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1249)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:975)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:550)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:384)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:308)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:158)
at $Proxy43.getLogin(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to debug the code and found for the soap header a handler is called which extends class named as Service. This class is present in jaxws jar.When I deploy in websphere the class Service is called from axis2 jar instead os jaxws jar.
I tried by removing the axis2 jars and pasting jaxws jars in plugins and lib folder of websphere but this has not worked.
Please can anyone help me how can I resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can any body please suggest some solution...I am still stuck on this. I made Configuration changes as Parent_Last. Then it gives me class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you should set WS-Security username token in the client. If you use SoapUi for testing add new outgoing WS-Security configuration (use Username WSS entry).